# How to connecting Laravel with AWS S3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

**please** help to *connecting laravel with aws s3*,

> could you please give me reference or article for this?
> `thank you`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create account s3
2. Create bucket
3. install in laravel packages for connecting
4. add data in .env for connecting

Answer (score 1):

you can use this official document of laravel for amazon s3 storage .

[Laravel Amazon S3 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#amazon-s3-compatible-filesystems)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).